# Sorting separately over different attributes in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a mongodb collection of ~80,000 documents. I want to display the top 200 documents per attribute on a webpage, where the user can sort by different attributes by using a dropdown menu on the webpage.

At the moment I'm returning a queryset per attribute and then combining them, but this is super slow:

```
from itertools import chain

tall_people =  People.objects().order_by('-height')[:200]
heavy_people = People.objects().order_by('-weight')[:200]
old_people = People.objects().order_by('-age')[:200]
rich_people = People.objects().order_by('-wealth')[:200]

people = list(set(chain(tall_people, heavy_people, old_people, rich_people)))

for person in people:
    do something....
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need to make all the queries up front? The user may only be interested in sorting on one field, so execute the query dynamically when you know which attribute you want and cache the result so the user can flip back and forth if they need.

Comment: OK, this sounds interesting. So you can pass user options into view.py? I'm fairly new to django and didn't realise this sort of thing was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think(haven't tested) you can use the initial query set object and sort it by different attributes with python's sorted

```
all_people =  People.objects().all()[:200]
tall_people = sorted(all_people, key=lambda person: person.height)
heavy_people = sorted(all_people, key=lambda person: person.weight)
old_people = sorted(all_people, key=lambda person: person.age)
rich_people = sorted(all_people, key=lambda person: person.wealth)
```

This will only save the database I/O overhead

Comment: This isn't equivalent. Taking the first 200 people then sorting them, isn't the same as sorting all the people and taking the top 200 per category...

Answer (score 0):

A *slightly* more efficient way is to fetch only the IDs for each group, and then do a final query to get the objects:

```
tall_people =  People.objects().values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-height')[:200]
heavy_people = People.objects().values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-weight')[:200]
old_people = People.objects().values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-age')[:200]
rich_people = People.objects().values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-wealth')[:200]

people_pks = set(chain(tall_people, heavy_people, old_people, rich_people))

people = People.objects.get(pk__in=people_pks)
```

The difference is that you're only fetching IDs for the first four queries, and then fetching objects in the last query. Currently you are fetching the entire rows in all four queries.

Obviously this has its limitations - passing a list of 200 IDs is probably fine, but doesn't scale well to thousands.